# Formatting columns on a Excel row VB .NET

Tags: excel, vb.net

I want to apply a style to an Excel row, only if the affected column has a value and is not empty.

However, I've tried with if, for and while instructions, and I didn't have a result.

My last code was:

```
Dim i As Excel.Range
Do While Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(xlWorksheet.Columns(i)) 
    xlWorksheet.Rows(5).Style = "FormatoHeader" 
Loop
```

I have to change the instruction?
Why my cycles are wrong?
And how can I format those cells, only for that row and only if the cell has data?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are not assigning to the variable i, and even then, is that the proper index for .Columns?

Comment: I don't assign a value because I want to check all the columns with values in that row

Answer (score 0):

Well, I forgot to mention that I wanted to format that row, because it is a header of a table.

My table is a tabular one, so it does have a predefined style.

```
Sheet.ListObjects.Add(Excel.XlListObjectSourceType.xlSrcRange,
            .Range("B5:X50"), Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes).Name = "CuteTable"
```

I changed the Excel style for another predefined one (in this case, I needed a greenish style):

```
Sheet.ListObjects("CuteStyle").TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium4"
```

And well, the short way to edit the header is to invoke the object `HeaderRowRange` and add the properties to it like this:

```
.ListObjects("CuteTable").HeaderRowRange.Font.ColorIndex = 1 'This is black
.ListObjects("CuteTable").HeaderRowRange.Interior.Color = 55555 'this is a green
```

The long way is to create a new style and store it in a variable:

```
Dim hstyle As Excel.Style=Sheet.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Styles.Add("hstyle")
hstyle.Font.Bold = True 
hstyle.Interior.Color = 333
```

And after it, apply the style to the header of the table:

```
Sheet.ListObjects("CuteTable").HeaderRowRange.Style = "hstyle"
```